# Alright, homework: How can X[i] possibly be interpretted the same as i[X] in C?

Tags: c, arrays, 32-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C arrays why is this true? a[5] == 5[a]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/in-c-arrays-why-is-this-true-a5-5a)

How can X[i] possibly be interpretted the same as i[X] in C?

I think the question is asking how an array[elementInArray] can be interpretted the same as elementInArray[array]

Also, unrelated on the same homework:
"Explain why the "hidden bit" of floating point format does not need to be represented." (in terms of 32 bit words of binary)

Comment: You have two unrelated questions here. You should split them. But the first one is a duplicate and the second one can probably be easily googled.

Answer (score 3):

In C, X[i] = i[X] = *(X + i) = *(i + X). As per commutative property, they are same.

Comment: Thank you! would you by any chance have an answer for the second part?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302172/float-precision-bits