# Why do compilers fix the digits of floating point number to 6?

Tags: c++, c++11, iso

According to ***The C++ Programming Language - 4th***, *section 6.2.5*:

> There are three floating-points types: ***float (single-precision)***, double (double-precision), and long double (extended-precision)

Refer to: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

> The true significand includes 23 fraction bits to the right of the binary point and an implicit leading bit (to the left of the binary point) with value 1 unless the exponent is stored with all zeros. ***Thus only 23 fraction bits of the significand appear in the memory format but the total precision is 24 bits (equivalent to log10(224) ≈ 7.225 decimal digits).***

→ The maximum digits of floating point number is `7` digits on `binary32 interchange format`. ***(a computer number format that occupies 4 bytes (32 bits) in computer memory)***

When I test on different compilers (like GCC, VC compiler)
→ It always outputs `6` as the value.

Take a look into `float.h` of each compiler
→ I found that `6` is ***fixed***.

**Question:**

- Do you know why there is a different here (between actual value theoretical value - 7 - and actual value - 6)?
  It sounds like ***"7"*** is more reasonable because when I test using below code, the value is still valid, while ***"8"*** is invalid
- Why ***don't the compilers check*** the interchange format for giving decision about the numbers of digits represented in floating-point (instead of using a fixed value)?

***Code:***

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main( )
{
    cout << numeric_limits<float> :: digits10 << endl;

    float f = -9999999;

    cout.precision ( 10 );

    cout << f << endl;
}
```

Comment: _"It always outputs 6 as the value."_ This can be deduced from the rest of your question but, in future, tell us what "it" is.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6302172/560648

Comment: Read http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're not *reading the documentation*.

---

#### [`std::numeric_limits<float>::digits10`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits10) is 6:

> The value of `std::numeric_limits<T>::digits10` is the number of base-`10` digits that can be represented by the type `T` without change, that is, any number with this many decimal digits can be converted to a value of type `T` and back to decimal form, without change due to rounding or overflow. For base-radix types, it is the value of digits (`digits-1` for floating-point types) multiplied by *log*<sub>10</sub>*(radix)* and rounded down.
>
> The standard 32-bit IEEE 754 floating-point type has a 24 bit fractional part (23 bits written, one implied), which may suggest that it can represent 7 digit decimals (`24 * std::log10(2)` is 7.22), but **relative rounding errors are non-uniform and some floating-point values with 7 decimal digits do not survive conversion to 32-bit float and back**: the smallest positive example is `8.589973e9`, which becomes `8.589974e9` after the roundtrip. **These rounding errors cannot exceed one bit in the representation, and digits10 is calculated as `(24-1)*std::log10(2)`, which is 6.92. Rounding down results in the value 6.**

---

#### [`std::numeric_limits<float>::max_digits10`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max_digits10) is 9:

> The value of `std::numeric_limits<T>::max_digits10` is the number of base-`10` digits that are necessary to uniquely represent all distinct values of the type `T`, such as necessary for serialization/deserialization to text. This constant is meaningful for all floating-point types.
>
> Unlike most mathematical operations, the conversion of a floating-point value to text and back is exact as long as at least `max_digits10` were used (`9` for `float`, `17` for `double`): it is guaranteed to produce the same floating-point value, even though the intermediate text representation is not exact. It may take over a hundred decimal digits to represent the precise value of a float in decimal notation.

Comment: I have refer to some wiki pages and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/numeric_limits/

Answer (score 1):

[`std::numeric_limits<float>::digits10`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits10) equates to [`FLT_DIG`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits), which is defined by the C standard :

> number of decimal digits, q, such that any floating-point number with q decimal digits can be rounded into a floating-point number with p radix b digits and back again without change to the q decimal digits,
>
> ⎧ p log10 b if b is a power of 10
>
> ⎨
>
> ⎩ ⎣( p − 1) log10 b⎦ otherwise
>
> FLT_DIG     6
>
> DBL_DIG     10
>
> LDBL_DIG     10

The reason for the value 6 (and not 7), is due to rounding errors - not all floating point values with 7 decimal digits can be losslessly represented by a 32-bit `float`. Rounding errors are limited to 1 bit though, so the `FLT_DIG` value was calculated based on 23 bits (instead of the full 24) :

```
23 * log10(2) = 6.92
```

which is rounded down to `6`.

Comment: The quote is poorly rendered.