# Reinterpreting int as float

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a float by setting its bits.
I read here that probably the best way is using memcpy.
That's the code I'm using

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

float i2f(int i) {
  float result;

  memcpy(&result, &i, sizeof(int));

  return result;
}

int main() {
  printf("Size of int is %d.\n", sizeof(int));
  printf("Size of float is %d.\n", sizeof(float));

  int i = 0x7fffff;
  float f = i2f(i);

  printf("int value is %d.\n", i);
  printf("float value is %f.\n", f);

  return 0;  
}
```

The output I get is

```
Size of int is 4.
Size of float is 4.
int value is 8388607.
float value is 0.000000.
```

Can someone explain why float value is zero ?

Comment: But float is a simple data type, and when it's value is returned, it will be copied.

Comment: Because it is so close to zero. Values close to 1.0f are as big as 0x3f800000 as integers.

Comment: to print the result of `sizeof` you [must use `%zu`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/940087/995714)

Comment: Stupid question probably, but what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @Mr Lister you can see the float value for a given representation.

Answer (score 3):

The bits of integer `0x7fffff` encode a `float` value that is very small, less than 2<sup>−126</sup>. The `%f` conversion specifier does not produce enough digits to show the value. Use `%g` or `%e` or specify many more digits, such as `%.99f`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, could you explain how did you know that it's so close to zero ?

Comment: @zzz_zzz http://www.binaryconvert.com/convert_float.html , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754

Comment: @zzz_zzz: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/6313398/298225](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6313398/298225).